# Create column of decimal type when creating a dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, types, apache-spark-sql, decimal

I would like to provide numbers when creating a Spark dataframe. I have issues providing decimal type numbers.

This way the number gets truncated:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([(10234567891023456789.5, )], ["numb"])
df = df.withColumn("numb_dec", F.col("numb").cast("decimal(30,1)"))
df.show(truncate=False)
#+---------------------+----------------------+
#|numb                 |numb_dec              |
#+---------------------+----------------------+
#|1.0234567891023456E19|10234567891023456000.0|
#+---------------------+----------------------+
```

This fails:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([(10234567891023456789.5, )], "numb decimal(30,1)")
df.show(truncate=False)
```

> TypeError: field numb: DecimalType(30,1) can not accept object 1.0234567891023456e+19 in type <class 'float'>

How to correctly provide big decimal numbers so that they wouldn't get truncated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is related to some differences in floating points representation between Python and Spark. You can try passing string values when creating dataframe instead:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("10234567891023456789.5", )], ["numb"])

df = df.withColumn("numb_dec", F.col("numb").cast("decimal(30,1)"))
df.show(truncate=False)
#+----------------------+----------------------+
#|numb                  |numb_dec              |
#+----------------------+----------------------+
#|10234567891023456789.5|10234567891023456789.5|
#+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: I was reading about it the whole day and found this same solution too. But I didn't have an idea of why this was happening. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try something as below -

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from decimal import *

schema = StructType([StructField('numb', DecimalType(30,1))])

data = [( Context(prec=30, Emax=999, clamp=1).create_decimal('10234567891023456789.5'), )]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=schema)

df.show(truncate=False)

+----------------------+
|numb                  |
+----------------------+
|10234567891023456789.5|
+----------------------+
```